# Calculate duration by rotating array from group dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope you could help me with this. I would like to calculate the duration using python.

The data looks like this

```
group_id, id, departure_time, arrival_time
1,1,61200,61800
1,2,18000,18600
2,1,32400,34200
2,2,64800,66600
2,3,77400,81000
```

The result that I would like to get

```
group_id,id,departure_time, arrival time, departure_rotate, duration
1,1,61200,61800, 18000, 43800
1,2,18000,18600,61200,43800
2,1,32400,34200,77400,43200
2,2,64800,66600,64800, 1800
2,3,77400,81000,32400,48600
```

Actually, duration = arrival_time - departure_rotate. However for minus result should be added (24*3600). Thanks in advance. I tried this so far but did not give the expected result. So I think the way that I ask will help.

```
df_duration = pd.DataFrame(df_trips[[
        "group_id", "id", "arrival_time"
    ]], copy = True)
 df_following = pd.DataFrame(df_trips[[
        "group_id", "id", "departure_time"
    ]], copy = True)

    df_following.columns = ["group_id", "id", "following_trip_departure_time"]
    df_following["trip_id"] = df_following["id"] - 1

df_duration = pd.merge(df_duration, df_following, on = ["group_id", "id"])
```

Comment: Is it a csv file your data stored in?

Comment: Yes it is in CSV file. Thanks

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: How are `departure_rotate` and  `duration` calculated? what's the logic and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Departure rotate is dearture_time rotated for each group_id, the last become the first and reverse.

Comment: @dexter I put what I have tried. Thanks

Comment: @anugrahilahi How do you calculate `departure_rotate`, Can you explain more?

Comment: Departure rotate is departure_time rotated for each group_id,  for example, the second group_id the daprture_time was 32400, 64800, 77400. It becomes77400, 64800, 32400.

Comment: Do you mean rotation, like shift by 1, or reversed? From the example, it seems like you're reversing the order of items.

Comment: Yes it is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the given dataframe `df` as:

```
# df
   group_id  id  departure_time  arrival_time
0         1   1           61200         61800
1         1   2           18000         18600
2         2   1           32400         34200
3         2   2           64800         66600
4         2   3           77400         81000
```

**To calculate `departure_rotate`**, you can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe `df` on the column `group_id` and then apply `transform` on the column `departure_time` which reverses the `departure_time` for the given group.

**To calculate `duration`**, you can subtract the `arrival_time` and `departure_rotate` column to get the `diff` and then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign the new values to `duration` column depending upon the `diff` is greater than `0` or not.

Use:

```
import numpy as np

df['departure_rotate'] = (
    df.groupby('group_id')['departure_time'].transform(lambda s: s[::-1]))

diff = df['arrival_time'].sub(df['departure_rotate'])
df['duration'] = np.where(diff > 0, diff, diff.add(24*3600))
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   group_id  id  departure_time  arrival_time  departure_rotate  duration
0         1   1           61200         61800             18000     43800
1         1   2           18000         18600             61200     43800
2         2   1           32400         34200             77400     43200
3         2   2           64800         66600             64800      1800
4         2   3           77400         81000             32400     48600
```